# Android REST access outside network

Tags: android, rest, routes

I'm trying to get access to a web service of a server (that I have inside a network) using REST from my Android phone. In the router, I have done "routing" to give access to all queries from outside but the router has user and password.

My question is if it's neccesary to add some code in the HTTP Post or HTTP Client to get access to my router because all connections give me `HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://myipaddress:myport refused`

I have tried with some code but this didn't work.

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Object... params) {
    kkk = ((Integer) params[2]);

    parametros = params;
    Log.i("SendOnlyOneFact", "Guardando datos de la actividad " + kkk);

    Thread.currentThread().setName("NA_SendOnlyOneFact-" + kkk);
    // Guardar los datos creados
    getActividades().get(kkk).saveData((android.app.Activity) params[1]);
    // Serializar los datos creados
    String cosa_serializada = getActividades().get(kkk).getMeasure()
            .serializeData(getActividades().get(kkk), (android.app.Activity) params[1]);

    // Obtener el XML a partir de ese arraylist
    // Enviarlo mediante REST
    HttpHost targetHost = new HttpHost(((GateDefinition) params[0]).getServer(),
            ((GateDefinition) params[0]).getPort(), "http");

    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://" + ((GateDefinition) params[0]).getServer() + ":"
            + ((GateDefinition) params[0]).getPort() + "/" + ((GateDefinition) params[0])
            .getWeb_service());
    // Also be sure to tell the server what kind of content we are sending
    httpPost.setHeader("content-type", "text/plain");

    // Something like this, but this doesn't work :(
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("login", "1234"));
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "1234"));
    try {
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, "UTF_8"));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(cosa_serializada, "UTF-8");
        entity.setContentType("text/plain");
        httpPost.setEntity(entity);

        // execute is a blocking call, it's best to call this code in a
        // thread separate from the ui's
        response = httpClient.execute(targetHost, httpPost);
    } catch (SocketException ex) {
        Log.e("SendOnlyOneFact", "No existe conexión con el servidor");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

**EDIT: I test it with data connection and it works, but with wifi it gives me this exception, and I don't know why!! :o**

Comment: simply try adding  nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ur login", "ur password"));

Comment: @FahadIshaque that didn't work :(

Comment: Did you give the necessary permissions in your manifest file?

Comment: @SerkanArıkuşu yes, it has internet permission. I had tested my server in localhost and it works fine, but now I want to test my server to work from every network (that is, from every smartphone in other networks).